# Are there any .js charting tools that don't use VML or SVG?

Tags: javascript, charts

now that this IE zero-day exploit has pretty much stalled the internet, is there any alternatives out there that don't use VML?  (IE7 & 8 can't render .svg that I am aware of..)

FYI:  http://blogs.cisco.com/security/ie-zero-day-and-vgx-dll/

to clarify:  as current experts are recommending the `deregistering` of vgx.dll for those with IE, this will put a kink in any IE browser < 9, which is why I am looking for a charting tool that does not use either of these technologies.

Comment: Use any chart framework based on Canvas isntead of SVG, you can find the list here: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries And just don't include the excanvas library.

Comment: don't know what to tell you.  with vgx.dll unregistered, a *whole lot* does not work.  (my tests are only from IE8 looking at samples provided by the sites with the libraries)

Comment: Ok, I see, you want to display charts as a Flash app instead of VML in older versions of IE. By the way, flotr2 are just Canvas-based charts that use flashcanvas.js (http://flashcanvas.net/) library. I think any Canvas-based chart can use this library and work in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

flotr2 appears to work..  (http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2/)

**update**

actually no.  only some charts work in flotr2..

However, I have found some others that will render, but they still have problems

- flotr2

  - http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2/
- JQuery GraphUp plugin

  - Bar charts work, bubbles are rendered as squares, but other examples won't work
  - http://geertdedeckere.be/shop/graphup/download/demo2/
- only works with bar charts

  - clientsidegchart
  - GWT charts without JSNI, browser plugins, or server round-trips

    - http://clientsidegchart.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/live-demo/v2_7/com.googlecode.gchart.gchartdemoapp.GChartDemoApp/GChartDemoApp.html

> ```
> below is my updated list of what won't work.
> ```

- JQChart
- Chartjs
- ShieldUI
- HighCharts
- amcharts
- canvasjs
- canvas xpress
- D3.js
- dc.js - Dimensional Charting Javascript Library
- dojo charts
- flot
- fusioncharts
- google charts
- Raphael
- jqplot
- plotly
- NVD3.js
- RGraph
- rickshaw
- xCharts
- YUI
- ZingChart
- ZoomCharts
- protovis
- http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/charting_v2/index_2.php

  - partially working, but still no.
- bluff
- JIT - JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit
- .jsCharts
- ejsCharts
- JQueryUI Visualize
- JQuery Sparklines

  - cool!  but No.
- JQChart
- tufteGraph
- jgcharts
- arcadiacharts
- dhtmlx
- elycharts
- jsxgraph
- kendo-ui charts
- morris.js
- svgware
- softwarefx

Answer (score 0):

i'd seriously recommend looking at just using js library to do the maths for you and using divs in various styles to display your graphs if you are stuck supporting browsers that don't play nice! i ended up using this technique for treemaps to bar graphs and pie charts while i was at my last big network job.